# Template won't embed on one entry page but fine on everything else

Tags: templates, solspace-freeform, embeds, entry

I'm trying to add my embedded contact form template to one page for a blog entry. I've never had an issue with this template or embedding it until now.

Here is my code.

```
{embed="inc/html_header" page_title="{page_title} - {site_name}" 
      page_description="{meta-description}"}
<div class="blog-page entry-main">
    {embed="inc/nav"}

    {embed="blog/listing"}
</div>

{embed="contact/form"}
 <!--Hey footer footer-->
{embed="inc/html_footer"}
```

So the embedded html_footer appears on the entry template page just fine along with my random  Hey footer comment. In fact, everything on this page displays correctly except for **{embed="contact/form"}**.

I've done so many things to try and fix this -- use snippets for the form, use conditionals to check for segment_3, etc, but still no success. The pages I'm trying to display have the root structure of:
 
/blog/entry/the-entry-post-title-whatever-user-enters

When I navigate to just /blog/entry/index.php. I see the footer, but also every single blog entry and the html header and footer embedded templates.

Any thoughts? I'm nearly going insane over this and even had a nightmare where I spent a day trying to figure this out. Dreams are not meant to infested with EE code. Thanks.

Comment: First: I should not use so many embeds. It's really bad for performance. Second: Where's the rest of the code? Is the problematic embed inside `exp:channel:entries`? Please, update your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I feel dumb -- all I needed to do was add dynamic="no" to my form template channel entries tag. Lesson learned

Comment: Don't beat yourself up @OP